# How can I use husky to check a git commit message format?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, husky

I'm trying to enforce a git commit message policy to keep my repositories clean and tidy. I've seen the official docs about server-side and client-side hooks and then I bumped on [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky).

So far I could work with the first but couldn't set up husky, I've still got plenty to learn. The main idea is to be able to work on a new workstation without having to manually set up any client-side hooks.

Could someone explain how I can set up husky to check my commit messages or even make an example?

This is my commit-msg hook in `project-root/githooks` folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

message_file = ARGV[0]
message = File.read(message_file)

$regex = /([resolved|fixed]) #([0-9])* ([A-Z])\w+/

if !$regex.match(message)  
  puts "[POLICY] Your message is not formatted correctly!"  
  puts "Message format must be like:"  
  puts "resolved #123 Case title (for features)"  
  puts "fixed #123 Case title    (for bugs)"  
  puts "First letter of 'Case title' must be capitalized!"  
  exit 1  
end
```

I've tried to add the script to the package.json:

```
"scripts": {  
  ... : ...,  
  "commitmsg": "sh hooks/commit-msg",  
  ... : ...  
}
```

The hook does not work. All messages pass. If put in .git/hooks it works normally.

[image: package.json and commit-msg hook in a test project]

Here's a screenshot of a test project with the package.json, the commit-msg hook and the error it gives out.

The same hook, put in .git/hooks folder, works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [issue 81](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/81)

First, check

```
npm config get ignore-scripts # should be false
```

Then in a git repo:

```
npm install husky --save-dev
```

You can then add hooks (here a pre-commit and pre-push) to `npm` (`package.json`), the idea being those hook definitions are versions in that `package.json` file (part of your git repo sources).

Although, [Ron Wertlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1334781/ron-wertlen) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785974/how-can-i-use-husky-to-check-a-git-commit-message-format/41787949#comment124014035_41787949) that **`npm` scripts for anything beside build/package are an anti-pattern**.
See [Jerry Zheng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9970477/jerry-zheng)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55203979/6309) for a better practice.

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/89b1f62d0f2f8b73cad2c70faec7b45d9957c41f/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f794844734d32522e706e67]

You can also declare existing regular bash hooks ([issue 92](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/92#issuecomment-271362648))

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "sh scripts/my-specific-hook.sh"
  }
}
```

You can then use [`validate-commit-msg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-commit-msg) to validate your commit message.

> add `"commitmsg": "validate-commit-msg"` to your npm scripts in `package.json`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help! As mentioned in the edit, I tried to configure the package.json file but it doesn't work at all. I tried the validate-commit-msg too, and that also doesn't work...  So far I could run a script ("postinstall": "sh hooks/setup_hooks.sh") to move my hooks in the .git/hooks folder.

Comment: @remmargorp on which OS are you working on? With which version of npm?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and npm is version 4.0.5

Comment: @remmargorp would register a npm test as `pre-commit` hook work? (just to get back to a simpler test case, before debugging your more complex script)

Comment: I tried that "precommit": "npm test" and it works fine. There's no test set up though ...

Comment: @remmargorp sure: is it possible to modify that npm test to make it do something more (like an echo). And then build up your commit hook from there?

Comment: As you can see in the Edit2 the "install" script is executed upon npm install. It moves my hook from  test/hooks/ to test/.git/hooks. This way it works fine. If I skip this part and the hook remains in the test/hooks folder and I try to commit I get the error shown in the image (bottom terminal).

Comment: Regarding the "npm test" approach, if I get it right I would just change the call slightly, but trying it out I get the same error. I have the idea that my hook uses variables that exist/are seen only if in the .git/hooks folder :(

Comment: @remmargorp you could try and implement your script in bash instead of ruby. That way, you should use only known variables.

Comment: npm scripts for enything beside build/package are an anti-pattern.  The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55203979/1334781 is much safer and superior to this one.

Comment: @RonWertlen Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 21):

With Husky 7+, you can add the following to `.husky/commit-msg` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

message="$(cat $1)"
requiredPattern="^(add|cut|fix|bump|make|start|stop|refactor|reformat|optimise|document|merge) .*$"
if ! [[ $message =~ $requiredPattern ]];
then
  echo "-"
  echo "-"
  echo "-"
  echo " Wrong commit message! "
  echo "The commit message must have this format:"
  echo "<verb in imperative mood> <what was done>"
  echo "Allowed verbs in imperative mood: add, cut, fix, bump, make, start, stop, refactor, reformat, optimise, document, merge"
  echo "Example: add login button"
  echo "-"
  echo "Your commit message was:"
  echo $message
  echo "-"
  echo "For more information, check script in .husky/commit-msg"
  echo "-"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: hey can you please give me full instructions  i wan to set this config in my project.

Comment: Once you install husky, just follow what I wrote and that's it

Comment: hey thanks for your reply , i followed and i am not able to get commit message in that variable 
message="$(cat $1)"
i tried to echo it it show 0,  is  their any other way i can get commit message  instead of $(cat $1)

Comment: so how do i get commit message, because $1 is not working..  please if you  get time reply..

Answer (score 5):

**Like this:**

First, add validate script in your husky config:

```
// package.json
{
 ...
 "husky": {
  "hooks": {
     "pre-commit": "npm test",
     // if you use validate-commit-msg, this can be "validate-commit-msg"
+    "commit-msg": "sh scripts/my-specific-hook.sh",
     ....
  }
 }
}
```

And then, have a try...

Everything seems to be OK.

Comment: This doesn't pass args to `my-specific-hook.sh`.

Comment: @mjakic husky passes certain arguments to your script detailed here -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky#access-git-params-and-stdin

Answer (score 3):

This is for `commitlint` integration [as per the docs](https://commitlint.js.org/#/guides-local-setup?id=install-husky):

```sh
# Add hook
npx husky add .husky/commit-msg 'npx --no-install commitlint --edit $1'
# or
yarn husky add .husky/commit-msg 'yarn commitlint --edit $1'
```

Most probably; you may easily customize it with something like this:

```sh
yarn husky add .husky/commit-msg 'sh scripts/my-specific-hook.sh $1'
```